# How to find the greatest value of $OA^2 - OB^2$, where $A$, $B$ lies on the sphere

Tags: inequality, analytic-geometry

Let $ A $, $ B $ be two points lie on the sphere 
$$ x^2 + y^2 + (z-1)^2 = 25 $$ so that $ AB=6 $. Find the greateast value of $OA^2 - OB^2$.

I tried
    \begin{align*}
 OA^2- OB^2 & = (\overrightarrow{OA}^2 -\overrightarrow{OB}^2)\\
 & = (\overrightarrow{OA} + \overrightarrow{OB}) (\overrightarrow{OA} - \overrightarrow{OB}) \\
 & = 2\cdot \overrightarrow{OM} \cdot \overrightarrow{BA}\\
 & \leqslant 2 \cdot OM . AB \\
&= 12 \cdot OM
 \end{align*}
    Where, $ M $ is midpoint of the segment $ AB $ and $O(0,0,0)$.
From here, I can not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P=(0,0,1)$ be the centre of the sphere.  By Pythagoras, $PM^2=5^2-3^2$, so $M$ lies on
$$
x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=16
$$
and $OM$ is maximised when $M=(0,0,5)$.  But the bound $OA^2-OB^2\leq 12 \max OM=60$ is too crude.

Instead, leave it as $2\overrightarrow{OM}\cdot\overrightarrow{BA}$ for now and further manipulate
$$
2\overrightarrow{OM}\cdot\overrightarrow{BA}
=2\overrightarrow{OP}\cdot\overrightarrow{BA}+2\overrightarrow{PM}\cdot\overrightarrow{BA}.
$$
But $\overrightarrow{PM}\perp\overrightarrow{BA}$, so it reduces to
$$
2\overrightarrow{OP}\cdot\overrightarrow{BA}.
$$
Now the bound $OA^2-OB^2\leq 2\cdot OP\cdot BA=12$ is actually attainable with $\overrightarrow{BA}=6\,\mathbf{k}$, e.g., $B=(4,0,-2), A=(4,0,4)$.